# metaprogram c++ code

Tags: c++, functional-programming, metaprogramming

New semester in my university started and I am once again "forced" to quit abstractions and explore the deep waters of low level programming in `c++`. My mind is already partially contamined with folds, high order functions, etc., and I don't find any fun in writing for example:

```
bool allEven = true;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   if (arr[i] % 2 != 0){
      allEven = false; 
      break;
   }
}
```

when I know that I can write `val allEven = arr forall (_ % 2 == 0)`.
My question is: is there any tool|technique|language construct|metaprogramming stuff, that can bring some c++ code without writing it actually? I need to the whole source but it can be eventually obfuscated, only machine is going to process it.
And please don't me accuse of being lazy, I value it as one of my best virtues. :-)

**EDIT** It's not entirely clear what are you asking for... At best, I would like to use something like `GWT` but instead compiling `Java` sources to `JavaScript` sources It would compile `Scala` or `Haskell` or `F#` to `C++` sources, but since I don't believe that something like this exists, I would like to have something... helpful. I appreciate the suggested anon functions, for example.

Comment: @coubeatczech val allEven = arr forall (_ % 2 == 0) your doing this in c++??...

Comment: @Chris Buckler: I'm guessing he's doing that in F# and frustrated by his inability to do the same in C++.

Comment: that is scala actually but the frustration is there

Comment: @coubeatczech--While I understand and agree with the desire to write things in a functional way, when in Rome, do as the Romans. Don't try to write C++ like Scala; this would be as bad as writing Scala like C++.  If you're in an imperative language, write imperative code.  Others who maintain the code later will thank you.

Comment: By the way shouldn't the first line be "bool allEven = true;"?

Comment: @Chuck ahh I see what hes asking now, thanks Chuck!

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear what you're really asking for, but if you're trying to write C++ that's more like your other code, you could do something like this:

```
bool allEven = 
    std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](bool a, int i) {return a && i & 1==0; }, 1);
```

This does use a lambda, which is new in C++0x. If you're using an older compiler that doesn't support lambdas, you could look into using Boost Lambda instead (in which case your code would be even closer to the example you've given).

Comment: Wouldn't find_if be a bit simpler here?

Comment: @templatetypedef: yes, but I was trying to imitate what he'd written as closely as possible.

Comment: the accumulate is a `fold`, I guess..?

Answer (score 3):

`bool is_even = std::find_if(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](int i) { return i%2 != 0; }) == arr.end();`

Answer (score 2):

With new algorithms in C++0x, there is `all_of`:

```
bool all_even = std::all_of(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
                            [](int i) { return i%2 == 0; });
```

Boost.Range allows less verbosity:

```
bool all_even = 
    0==boost::count_if(arr, [](int i){ return i%2 != 0;});
```

Hopefully, Boost.Range will soon offer `all_of`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Boost.Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/index.html) library, it enables you to write close(er) to functional style of programming in C++.